Forge viewer selection colour hidden for selected item
Currently using Autodesk ForgeViewer 7. We have a model that contains piping, pipes can be broken up into sections such as elbows etc.
As we don't want the user to select individual sections of the piping, we have some custom traversal logic which finds the first parent node enriched with particular properties.
We then call viewer.select on the found parentId.
Theres a little flash, I guess as we're firing two events original node click, followed by parent select. This is fine.
However, the selection colour seems to be hidden under the grey colour of the pipe. Notice the first attached image below, you can see the blueish colour bleeding through the pipe joins.
I know the whole pipe is selected as when I drag around in the viewer or resize my browser, it appears like image 2. Fully blue.
Can anyone offer any advice on what the problem could be? Or any potential solutions?
Thanks in advance,




Please add a relevant code snippet of you're now coloring the pipe

Added snippet. The selection is working as on moving around the model or resizing the browser window you can see the nodes are selected. It's just the selection colour seems to be being applied under the pipe material not on top?

This is likely caused by a change that was introduced in Viewer v7 where selecting a group of elements will use a simple color tint instead of the see-through effect used for selection of individual elements, for performance reasons.
For more details please see https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-selection-highlighting.

Thanks again Petr! I'll give this a whirl!
